# Gmail redirection after sign in

Tags: gmail, callbackurl

When I try to go through the specific mail page link without sign in, gmail redirects me to the `sign-in page`.

But after I sign in it always redirects me to the *inbox page* (as below image), and not to that specific mail page.

[image]

How can I go to the specific page link after sign in?

Does gmail have such feature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because You have chosen the Inbox as a default option. You can change it from Setting in Inbox. Uncheck "Redirect Gmail to inbox.google.com"

To Open Setting Menu Please check the Below Screenshot.
[image]

Please check the attached Screenshot.
[image]

Comment: check answer, I have edited it. Don't forget to rate answer.

Comment: Please go through the link of picture that i have shared and suggest me the answer.